# Can Data Driven tests in TestCafe using JSON work with JSON having multiple attributes for each test?

Tags: json, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have plenty of data-driven tests already written in testcafe until now based on this example.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/create-data-driven-tests.html

Has anyone attempted to do a JSON data-driven test w/testcafe with a JSON file like the sample below?

```
[
       {
            "testcasename": "Check for Rate Classes -1",
            "rateclasses": "{
                   "classname": "SC",
                   "classvalue": 1
             }
        },

]
```

This is the code I use to iterate through the JSON file. Now my dilemma is can there be a multi-level data set routine written?

```
dataSet.forEach(userdata => {
    test(`Enter '${userdata.testcasename}'`, async t => {
        my code here
    });
});
```

Would it look like

```
dataSet.forEach(userdata => {
    test(`Enter '${userdata.testcasename}'`, async t => {
              some code here for the 1st level attributes
               dataSet.forEach(userdatasubattributes => {
                some code here for the repeating attributes for each test case
                }

       });
});
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

UPDATE

found that the construct needs to work like this:

```
[
       {
            "testcasename": "Check for Rate Classes -1",
            "rateclasses": " [
             {
                   "classname": "SC",
                   "classvalue": 1
             }
          ] 
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
dataSet.forEach(userdata => {
        test(`Enter '${userdata.testcasename}'`, async t => {  
            for(let i = 0, l = userdata.rateclasses.length; i < l; i++) {
                console.log ("Class Name", userdata.rateclasses[i].classname) 
                console.log ("Class Value", userdata.rateclasses[i].classvalue) 

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper [JSON syntax](https://www.json.org/json-en) for your tests with multi-level data, which is set as you mentioned in your UPDATE section.

You can also use the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to see how your existing objects are converted to the JSON format.

Comment: Looking to see how I can now write the dataset to iterate through the multi-level data.

Comment: This code needs to be adjusted. dataSet.forEach(userdata => {
    test(`Enter '${userdata.testcasename}'`, async t => {
              some code here for the 1st level attributes
               dataSet.forEach(userdatasubattributes => {
                some code here for the repeating attributes for each test case
                }

       });
});